# Css для TableView. на пустую неинициализированную колонку не прописывается стиль

Tags: java, css, javafx

Я использую отдельный CSS для DialogPane

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
dialogPane.getStylesheets()
.add(getClass().getResource("../sample/dialog.css").toExternalForm());
```

Вопрос : Как убрать "незакрашенную" часть ? Не знаю как правильно её описать, поэтому приложу изображение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CSS :

```
 .dialog-pane {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

.dialog-pane .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.dialog-pane:header .header-panel {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

.dialog-pane:header .header-panel .label {
    -fx-font-style: italic;
    -fx-font-size: 2em;
}

.table-view{
-fx-background-radius: 20;
-fx-opacity:0.80;
-fx-background-color : transparent;
-fx-background-radius: 0;
-fx-background-insets: 0 0 10 0;
-fx-padding: 0 0 10 0;
-fx-effect: dropshadow(two-pass-box,rgb(10,101,107),15,0.0,0.1,3)
}


.table-view .column-header-background {
-fx-background-color : transparent;
-fx-background-radius: 0;
-fx-background-insets: 0 0 10 0;
-fx-padding: 0 0 10 0;
-fx-effect: dropshadow(two-pass-box,rgb(10,101,107),15,0.0,0.1,3)
}

.table-view .column-header, .table-view .filter{
-fx-size: 35;
-fx-border-width: 0 0 10 0;
-fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-view .column-header-background .label{
-fx-border-style: solid;
-fx-border-width: 0.25px;
-fx-border-radius:16;
-fx-border-opacity:0,5;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.table-view .column-header,
.table-view .column-header .filler,
.table-view .column-header-background .filler {
-fx-size: 35;
-fx-border-width: 0 0 10 0;
-fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Это решило мою проблему.